# How to resolve a relative directory path to canonical path in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: matlab, path, directory, octave

It happens that your application encounters a directory path that is relative to current folder or uses double dot for navigation, e.g. `C:\A\B\..\C`. This obviously is equivalent to the *canonical path* `C:\A\C`. How can one resolve the path to its canonical form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I know to convert a path to its canonical form is using [`cd`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cd.html) command:

```
oPath = cd(cd(iPath));
```

Note that this would fail if the path does not exist on your file system.

Answer (score 8):

This one uses the java io interface:

```
jFile=java.io.File(iPath);
oPath=jFile.getCanonicalPath;
```

It wouldn't need to change matlab's directory. It has other useful methods that may be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it, without potentially throwing an exception, is using the [what](https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/what.html) command:

```
pathInfo = what(iPath);
if ~isempty(pathInfo)
    iPath = pathInfo.path;
end
```